# Object Required Error - Why would this be out of scope?

Tags: arrays, object, vbscript, scope

I want to use a global array of objects of my own class (`Markers` class), which have data loaded in from a recordset. I can load the data from the recordset into the objects in the array just fine it seems, but when I try to access the values in the one of the objects in the array, it gives an "Object Required" error. I don't understand why my `Markers()` array of `Marker` class objects is getting destroyed or going out of scope.

```
Dim Markers(6)

Public Function GetItemSet(ByVal item)
  'gets user input and returns a recordset object (just 1 record/row) from a SQL database
  'working properly
End Function

Public Sub LoadMarkers(ByVal rs)
  For i = 0 to 6
    Set Markers(i) = New Marker
  Next

  MsgBox rs.Fields.Item("TextLine1").Value
  Markers(0).TextLine(0) = rs.Fields.Item("TextLine1").Value
  Markers(0).TextLine(1) = rs.Fields.Item("TextLine2").Value

  'the above is just what I'm using to test functionality, no errors so far
End Sub

Public Function GetMarkerText(ByVal mrkr, ByVal line)
    GetMarkerText = Markers(mrkr).TextLine(line)
End Function
```

In the other script I've tried both using `Markers(0).TextLine(0)` directly as well as calling `GetMarkerText(0,0)` to get the value... both methods result in object required error either on the line I directly try to access it or in the one line of code for `GetMarkerText`. `LoadMarkers` sub seems to have no issues accessing the `Markers()` array of `Marker` class objects, but then it seems to get destroyed after that sub ends? I'm new to VBScript so maybe I just don't quite understand how the scope is working but I can't see why this shouldn't work. Any ideas?

EDIT: Am I just a noob with Classes? Here's the relevant portion of the `Markers` class definition:

```
Class Marker
  Private m_Name
  Private m_TxtLines(6)
  Private m_ItemNum
  Private m_FontSize
  Private m_FontType
  Private m_Length

  Private Sub Class_Initialize( )
    m_Name = "Unnamed"
    m_ItemNum = 0
    m_Length = 1

    For i = 0 To 6
       m_TxtLines(i) = ""
    Next

    m_FontSize = 8
    m_FontType = "Arial"
  End Sub

  'Name Property
  Public Property Get Name
    Name = m_Name
  End Property

  Public Property Let Name(marker)
    m_Name = marker
  End Property

  'TextLine Property for holding up to 7 lines of marker text
  Public Property Get TextLine(index)
    TextLine(index) = m_TxtLines(index)
  End Property

  Public Property Let TextLine(index, txt)
    m_TxtLines(index) = txt
  End Property

  'ItemNum Property
  Public Property Get ItemNum
    ItemNum = m_ItemNum
  End Property

  Public Property Let ItemNum(num)
    m_ItemNum = num
  End Property

  'Length Property
  Public Property Get Length
    Length = m_Length
  End Property

  Public Property Let Length(len)
    m_Length = len
  End Property

  'FontSize Property 
  Public Property Get FontSize
    FontSize = m_FontSize
  End Property

  Public Property Let FontSize(pts)
    m_FontSize = pts
  End Property

  'FontType Property
  Public Property Get FontType
    FontType = m_FontType
  End Property

  Public Property Let FontType(font)
    m_FontType = font
  End Property

  'Haven't added my methods in yet
End Class
```

Comment: Hold on, I think the problem may be in my Class code... checking something, will delete question if so.

Comment: I was just about to ask you to post the `Marker` class definition then spotted your comment.

Comment: @Lankymart just edited post to add the TextLine property definition

Comment: Need more then that, ideally need to see the full definition.

Comment: @Lankymart there you go. Right now I don't have any methods in there, still trying to get this first portion working...

Comment: Actually, I just put in `MsgBox Markers(0).TextLine(0)` at the end of the `LoadMarkers()` sub and its printing a blank, although the MsgBox using the recordset is printing the correct value.... So it seems my assignment statement is the piece that's broken, did I do something wrong writing my class?

Comment: No I can't see what is wrong it looks fine. Thought is was lack of `Property Set` but don't think that's relevant now.

Comment: Actually is it not your `Property Get` assignment for `TextLine`? Think it should be `TextLine = m_TxtLines(index)`. You shouldn't need `index` on the `TextLine` assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After staring at the class definition for a while think I may have spotted the culprit.

The assignment in...

```
Public Property Get TextLine(index)
```

is not correct. It should just point to...

```
TextLine = m_TxtLine(index)
```

not

```
TextLine(index) = m_TxtLine(index)
```

Comment: Thank you that was it, a little proofreading can go a long way.